# python numpy: define your own element wise matrix operand

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, coordinates, element

I am almost sure I have seen that somewhere but I cannot find it back.

Is there an operand in numpy or python which will let me choose how to combine to matrixes by their elements coordinates?

for example

```
A = a[i,j]
C = c[i,j]
```

I want to specify, as an example

```
D = d[i,j] = (a[i,j]*c[j,i])/(i+j)
```

Many thanks, spent nearly 2h searching for the function I did see somewhere some weeks ago...

Comment: it should be  numpy einsum

Comment: and indeed it was, thx a lot Aly